# IE8 back button resetting form

Tags: html, caching, ssl, internet-explorer-8

I have a page in ASP Classic that contains a form, when the user submits the form he presses the back button of IE8 and he fills the form again, he reuses almost all of the data that he entered previously.

We just implemented SSL on the site and now when the user hits the back button of IE8 the fields of the form are reset. I tested it in Chrome and it keeps the state of the form, but IE8 does not.

How can I force IE8 to not clear the content of the form when the back button is pressed?

This is the response header from IE8:

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Tue, 25 Nov 2014 03:04:49 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
pragma  no-cache
cache-control   private
Content-Type    text/html
Expires Sat, 15 May 1999 04:00:00 GMT
Cache-control   private
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Set-Cookie  asdfommited; Expires=Tue, 25-Nov-2014 04:04:15 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie  asdfommited; Expires=Tue, 25-Nov-2014 04:04:15 GMT; Path=/
```

This is the response header from Chrome:

```
Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:https://www.ommited.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)             Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36

Resonse Headers:
cache-control:private, private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 25 Nov 2014 02:57:49 GMT
Expires:Sat, 15 May 1999 04:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Vary:Accept-encoding
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the issue. The following instructions were in the ASP page, which were forcing the page to not use cache. I just removed those lines and now when the backspace is pressed, it is showing the values that were entered in the form previously.

```
Response.Expires=15;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = 'May 15, 1999';
Response.AddHeader ("pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AddHeader ("cache-control", "private");
Response.CacheControl = "private";
```